# Examples for a reactjs frontend for an aiohttp backend

Tags: reactjs, aiohttp

Hi I've built an aiohttp app which functions as an autonomous system running periodic tasks & returns json & text responses for getting status of operations & supports receiving triggers for tasks using various GET, PUT & POST requests.

eg. I have implemented a GET request for retrieving the current running list of tasks as a json response

I want to use a reactjs UI as a frontend that consumes my aiohttp app's requests. This react app would be like an admin panel for the aiohttp app.

**I see there are two architectural options here -**

**option1.** embed the react app into the aiohttp app's codebase & have aiohttp/gunicorn serve the whole project as one server

**option2**. separate aiohttp backend with react frontend

Rather than have aiohttp serve the static files & html for the react app, I want to implement logical separation of concerns by running the reactjs app on a separate docker container with the following **expected behaviour**

1. if aiohttp API endpoint is down & react app is up -

react app shows "backend not available" in UI components that depend on & pull data from an API implemented in the aiohttp backend

2. if both aiohttp & react are up, the react app should be able to periodically call various aiohttp handlers it needs to populate the UI components with data & show a responsive UI

This would also help the react frontend integrate with other rest APIs in my stack (eg docker) so I can build a complete admin interface for my whole stack

I was not able to find a succint example that helps me implement a react frontend with lazy loading for such an application (also need to understand if this can be made to work with push requests where the aiohttp app calls the react app to avoid a poll)

I am a complete newbie in the JS world but have done a lot of work on python, asyncio & aiohttp

**Questions -**

1. have i chosen a robust option (option 2) & are there some known/common issues 
   that I could have avoided with option 1?
2. Please help me with a simple step by step example or a working code repo of how to build a react frontend for my app without having to change my aiohttp handlers too much
3. Can i add functionality to my aiohttp app whereby it can call the react app for submitting status updates vs. waiting for the react app to call the UI in the next poll

i'm sure the questions expose my level of ignorance about how this stuff works. Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Silent downvoters ate my question so here is something i'm using as a stopgap until i figure things out. Even if the -1 brigade gets hold of this, at least it will help someone who came here from google.

i found that this project - https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp_admin builds on this project - https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin so you can build an aiohttp admin interface using Angular.

the publisher of ng-admin has also released https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest - here is something i tried with my aiohttp handlers (you will need CORs if you want to follow option 2 like i did)

aiohttp_admin has an open issue for moving to admin-on-rest https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp_admin/issues/359

so I guess this will solve the issue for everyone who needs this functionality & is not a reactjs programmer

This is what i could get to work (am still trying to solve pagination errors, need to work on a custom restclient for my app)

The examples below should help someone with a view of all the code that needs to happen to get admin-on-rest to talk to your aiohttp API & how to serialize your responses. Use with care this does not work 100%

aiohttp handler -

```
async def get_limits(request):
    """
    ---
    description: This end-point lists task IDs.
    tags:
    - scheduler
    produces:
    - application/json
    responses:
        "200":
            description: successful operation returns task IDs
        "405":
            description: invalid HTTP Method
    """
    limits = copy(request.app.limits)
    pages = str(len(limits.keys()))
    response_ = serialize_limits(limits)
    return json_response(response_[0], headers={
        "X-Total-Count": pages, "X-Content-Range": pages})
```

Serializer -

```
import toastedmarshmallow
from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class LimitSchema(Schema):
    """
    schema for scheduler limits
    """
    resource = fields.Str()
    limit = fields.Int()
    id = fields.Int()


class Limit(object):
    """
    model for scheduler limits
    """

    def __init__(self, resource, limit, id):
        self.resource = resource
        self.limit = limit
        self.id = id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Limit(resource={self.resource!r})>'.format(self=self)


def serialize_limits(dict_):
    """
    output a serialized version of an input dict
    :param dict_:
    :return:
    """
    limits = []
    schema = LimitSchema(many=True)
    schema.jit = toastedmarshmallow.Jit
    id = 0
    for key, value in dict_.items():
        limits.append(Limit(resource=key, limit=value, id=id))
        id += 1

    return schema.dump(limits)
```

reactjs -

```
list.js -

import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField } from 'admin-on-rest';

export const Limitlist = (props) => (
    <List title="Limits" {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="resource" />
            <TextField source="limit" />
        </Datagrid>
        </List>
);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { jsonServerRestClient, simpleRestClient, Admin, Resource} from 'admin-on-rest';
import myApiRestClient from './avionicsRestClient';
import { Limitlist } from './limits';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';


const App = () => (
<Admin restClient={myApiRestClient}>
<Resource name="limits" list={Limitlist} />
</Admin>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say combining Javascript frontend with Python backend is somewhat common case for larger teams, especially when doing HTTP-based microservices. There are multiple strategies how to handle e.g. authentication - API gateway, JWT tokens...

In the case of one Aiohttp backend (directly accessible over HTTP, not proxied throught Node.js) and one Node.js frontend - no microservice stuff etc. - I'm currently doing such project: [pyladies-courseware](https://github.com/messa/pyladies-courseware) but it's totally WIP (but already has real users). I've also created some examples/demos (mostly as my personal experiments):
[github.com/messa/aiohttp-nextjs-demo-chat](https://github.com/messa/aiohttp-nextjs-demo-chat), [github.com/messa/redis-rpc-nodejs-python-demo](https://github.com/messa/redis-rpc-nodejs-python-demo)

The most headache-inducing areas were:

- authentication, cookies, CORS, OAuth etc.

  - whether to use the same domain (origin) for both backend and frontend (needs some nginx routing, or proxying middleware)
- how to pass data from backend to frontend

  - both from backend to browser and from backend to frontend Node.js (when doing SSR)
  - I've decided to use GraphQL to make things easier (easier to code, but yet another tech to learn)

    - but this may not apply well to the admin interface use-case
    - GraphQL, Aiohttp and client-side Apollo or Relay support Websockets - for any kind if on-demand updates, notifications etc.

If you are OK to have the React app statically exported (into HTML and JS files) then of course you can serve them directly from aiohttp or even from CDN and you need no Node.js at production runtime.

My personal prediction (or at least a wish :) ) for 2019 is that there will emerge a web framework that combines Python backend with Javascript React UI to gain the most strength from both languages and ecosystems.